# intersection and union of two pyspark dataframe on the basis of a common column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframe, A & B

A has two column `date, symbol`
B has two column `date2 entity`

i just want to get `union` and `intersection` of these two df on the basis of dates

for example if df A as

```
+----------+------+
|      date|symbol|
+----------+------+
|2013-08-30|     A|
|2013-08-30|   AAL|
|2013-08-30|   AAP|
|2013-08-30|  AAPL|
|2013-08-30|  ABBV|
+----------+------+
```

and B as:

```
+----------+-------------+
|       day|entity_ticker|
+----------+-------------+
|2013-08-30|            A|
|2013-08-30|          AAL|
|2013-08-30|          AAP|
|2013-08-30|         AAPL|
|2013-08-30|          ABC|
+----------+-------------+
```

i just want union as

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
|       dd |union_of_sybols                 |
+----------+--------------------------------+
|2013-08-30|            [A,AAL,AAP,AAPL,ABBV,ABC]|
+----------+--------------------------------+
```

and intersection as:

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
|       dd |intersection_of_sybols          |
+----------+--------------------------------+
|2013-08-30|            [A,AAL,AAP,AAPL]    |
+----------+--------------------------------+
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have your tried anything? please share those as well

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, just got confuse, how should i proceed, like should i do that with sql (which is slow) or joining the dataframe (not getting the result what i want), so i'm looking for solution, which i'm unable to find from myself.

Comment: just include what you've tried. I am working on the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get benefited with `union` and `intersect` functions for dataframes. After you `union` or `intersect`, final step would be to `groupBy` and use `collect_set` *inbuilt function* as aggregation

For union

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
#union of two dataframes
A.union(B).groupBy(f.col('date').alias('dd')).agg(f.collect_set('symbol').alias('union_of_symbols')).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+----------+------------------------------+
|dd        |union_of_symbols              |
+----------+------------------------------+
|2013-08-30|[AAL, AAP, ABC, A, AAPL, ABBV]|
+----------+------------------------------+
```

And for intersection

```
#intersection of two dataframes
A.intersect(B).groupBy(f.col('date').alias('dd')).agg(f.collect_set('symbol').alias('intersection_of_symbols')).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+----------+-----------------------+
|dd        |intersection_of_symbols|
+----------+-----------------------+
|2013-08-30|[AAL, AAP, A, AAPL]    |
+----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: can u please help how it is taking day and date as common one?

Comment: can you explain a little bit?

Comment: yes sure, i just wanted to understand the background functioning of union and intersection. I mean how it detects that `date` from A and `day` in B are the one which it need to take common.

Comment: spark renames the second dataframe as that of first dataframe. The order and column numbers should match though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171445/discussion-between-ggupta-and-ramesh-maharjan).